# Height=device-height and window.innerHeight

Tags: html, css, mobile

When i set `width=device-width` viewport property it work as - `window.innerWidth` changes accordingly by devices but when i change `height=device-height` it doesn't work - the `window.innerHeight` value doesn't change at all! So what is the point setting `height=device-height` property? I'm testing it on mobile Chrome.

Here is the code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640px, height=320px">
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        x = window.innerWidth;
        y = window.innerHeight;

        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "width: "+x;
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "height: "+y;
    }
</script>
```

The effect is: width: 640 but height: 279(!). Changing it to anything else - still no results.

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: Code? Screenshot? JSfiddle? Diagram of what you want to achieve? Please provide more information because we can't see your site :(

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi I've updated my question so can You try to answer it?

Comment: @Daniel Cheung I've updated my question so can You try to answer it?